# Repeat filter date in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I How i can filter post by date my code is:
My View is:

```
<div>
    <h4>filter by date</h4>
    <input type="date" name="filterByDate" ng-model="filterByDate.date"/>
</div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterByDate  ">
                <p>Title: {{item.title}}</p>
                <p>Date: {{item.date.toDateString()}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
 app.controller('ItemController', function($scope){
    var items= [
        {
            title: "item1",
            date: new Date(2015,1,15)
        },
        {
          title: "item2",
          date: new Date(2015,2,16)
        }
    ];


    $scope.items= items;
});
```

I try filter only post for current date who is select from input, but result is not filtered.
Tell me, where wrong.

Comment: try replacing `filterByDate` with `mediumDate` and see if it works

Comment: no, this do not worked

Comment: Where is the definition of `filterByDate`? Any working code like JSFiddle?

Comment: I am not declared `filterBydate` nowhere . i just have `<input type="date"  ng-model="filterByDate.date"/>`